# How to filter described images by name in DescribeImagesRequest?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to check whether a specific AMI exists. So, I'm doing:

```
val filter = new Filter().withName("Name").withValues(amiName)
val result = ec2.describeImages(new DescribeImagesRequest().withFilters(filter))
result.getImages.size() > 0
```

(code is Scala and not Java, but that's not really relevant). I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The filter 'Name' is invalid
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:644) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:338) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:190) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:6199) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeImages(AmazonEC2Client.java:2905) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
```

How do I correctly define a filter to the DescribeImagesRequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR - use `name` instead of `Name` as the key.

To investigate, I turned to my local installation of ec2 tools, and ran

```
ec2-describe-images -o self -F name=myaminame
```

Got a similar error that was more Google friendly:

```
Filter definitions must have format 'name=value', but found 'name'
```

Googlging got me to this [blog post](http://wingleungchan.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/ec2-describe-instances-filter.html), and afterwards this worked from the command line:

```
ec2-describe-images -o self -F "name=myaminame"
```

Now, after this unrelated excursion, I just found the simple problem: I tried `Name` as key, while in fact the key should be lowercase `name`.

Comment: Cheers! Just had the exact same problem, I was doing `Description` rather than `description`